# Error Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, nodejs, typescript, mongoose

Al listar los elementos en la base de datos me aparece el error "Converting circular structure to JSON", ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Modelo BD

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: true},
    created_at: Date,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Listar los datos

```
 import express from 'express';
 const router = express.Router();
 const Post = require('../model/post');


  //todos los post
 router.get('/posts', function (_req, res) {
        const mini = Post.find();
        res.json(mini);
    });
 module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inténtalo así:

```
router.get('/posts', function (_req, res) {
    Post.find()
        .exec(function(err, posts) {
            res.json(posts); 
        });
});
```

La función [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) devuelve un objeto tipo *Query*, no devuelve los datos directamente, tienes que llamar `exec` sobre este objeto y pasarle un *callback*.  El error se debe a que no puede serializar el objeto como JSON.